# How do I style links in the w3.css framework?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have created many simple web pages in HTML and CSS and understand all the basic concepts (page structure, nature of cascading, etc.)

I'm using the W3.CSS responsive framework for the first time.

Just as one example, I'm not happy with the default link style. I would rather it be colored and perhaps a different font weight, as opposed to underlined.

I can think of two ways this might happen. I am wondering what considerations might arise when choosing between these ways.

(1) If link-styling classes are present in the framework, I can add them to my link.

(2) I attach my own style sheet. This would be the first time I add a style sheet overriding a framework, so what do I need to consider to make sure I don't upset the functioning of other parts of the framework?

Answer (score 1):

When customising frameworks, W3.CSS, Bootstrap, Foundation or any other, most developers will attach their own style sheet and override the default framework styles they want to modify.

In general this is the way to go because you don't loose your customisations when you update the framework.

As you noted, sometimes link styling classes may be an option and if they are, then it would make sense to use them instead. You may find though that the styling classes are too limited and don't let you do all you need.

> what do I need to consider to make sure I don't upset the functioning
>   of other parts of the framework?

As long you have some CSS experience it will be clear to you which styling rules you can easily change and which you need to take care with.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Stop right there... do not use a framework until you have a solid understanding of HTML and CSS. - ESPECIALLY don't use something made by w3schools.com.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

```
<!doctype html><!-- declare the type of document (html) -->
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- document setup stuff -->
    <title>Example page</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='framework-stylesheet.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='my-stylesheet.css' />

    <!-- you can put styles in the document... which I'll do for example - but you should most likely put them in an external file as linked to above -->
    <style>
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: lightgreen;
      }

      a { /* your're additions and overrides... */
       color: 'im unique';
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- content -->
    <a href='#'>example link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understated my experience;  I have edited the question. It's about what I might need to consider when using a framework--considerations that are not present when doing a simple page such as you present.

Comment: If you understand cascading style sheets - then you can include any 'set of css rules' ("framework") and AFTER that... add to / override anything you need to do...

Comment: I'm a total idiot for even trying an answer this 'question' - but the fact that my time is only rewarded with a downvote is hilarious.